# Как загрузить файл на сервер, с помощью multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Когда я отправляю файл на сервер, то получаю пустой объект, хотя делаю все по видео.

1. Если использовать с FileReader

**Фронт**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="load" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input
      @change="loadFile($event)"
      type="file"
      name="image"
      accept="image/*"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadFile(e) {
      if (window.FileReader && window.File) {
        const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        if (file && reader) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          reader.addEventListener("error", (err) => {
            throw err;
          });
          reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            this.image = { res: reader.result, file };
          });
        } else {
          this.image = {
            res: "",
            file: {},
          };
        }
      }
    },
    load() {
      if (Object.keys(this.image).length) {
        // { res: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pjxz...', file: { lastModified: 1638642563466, ... } }
        console.log(this.image);

        const res = fetch("http://localhost:3000/upload", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ image: this.image }),
        });

        res
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Сервер**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '../uploads'))
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, `${file.originalname}-${Date.now()}`);
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  // Приходит пустой файл
  // { image: { res: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4...', file: {} } }
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
});

module.exports = app;
```

2. Если использовать FormData

**Фронт**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="load" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input
      @change="loadFile($event)"
      type="file"
      name="image"
      accept="image/*"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadFile(e) {
      const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

      if (file) {
        this.image = file;
      }
    },
    load() {
      if (Object.keys(this.image).length) {
        const fd = new FormData();

        fd.append("image", this.image);

        const res = fetch("http://localhost:3000/upload", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(fd),
        });

        res
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Сервер**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '../uploads'))
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, `${file.originalname}-${Date.now()}`);
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  // Приходит объект
  // {}
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Если вы собираетесь использовать multer, то зачем  тут эти приседания с json? Взять и отправить FormData, и не городить огород

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я поначалу так и делал, но FormData просто возвращала пустой объект

Comment: @AlexeyTen, изменил вопрос, посмотрите, что не так с FormData

Comment: Всё ещё непонятные попытки отправить json вместо mulipart/form-data

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, помогло. Просто зациклился ставить JSON.stringify() и в headers "Content-Type": "application/json" при запросах. Все это убрал, отправил и получил файл! Еще раз спасибо